# TextMesh Pro Material Preset Animation not working in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I am trying to animate TestMeshPro Material Preset, from fade to opaque. Its not working for me. Once material is assigned, it never changes even after assigning different materials in animation frames. Is it possible to create animation through material preset?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not animating the Material itself, but the Text Mesh's color value. So when you change it to opaque/faded, it will remain as such for any material you assign.

Additionally, you can't animate the Material itself from the Animation (At least for TextMesh presets). Your safest best to animate the Material would be through code, perhaps with a Tweening library. But note that animating a Material directly will change the look of all objects that utilize that same Material.

Comment: Thanks Hejden for your reply. I have also tried animating the material but it didn't worked. And as you said we can't animate the material, I will give it try through code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating some public materials in the script and assigned it in the inspector. Then I created event handlers in the animation and assigned materials from the function and it worked. There can be other better way but this is one way to work with.